# how to copy a message into picture or vice versa?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

What would happen if u do
copy /b "image.png" + "text.text"
how and where can we see the result
and plz suggest the same operation if in linux shell
And does it provide any sort of Encryption to the message

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't think the copy command as anything to do with steganography.

Comment: Are you trying to overlay the text into the image using `copy`?

Answer (score 1):

That's a primitive steganography technique. It provides no encryption whatsoever, the message is still readable in plaintext. It's hidden and you're unlikely to stumble upon it accidentally (unless your image viewer is particularly picky and warns you about something appended at the end of the image). But if you know there's something supposed to be hidden somewhere in the image, then the message can be effortlessly viewed with any hex editor or extracted with the `strings` tool.

It works for some formats (in particular JPEG and PNG), sort of works for others (TAR will work, but you'll get warnings about appended data with the GNU tar) and won't work at all with some (text files, obviously; it will also break some files).

You can do a similar thing on *NIX systems using `cat`. I'll leave figuring out the exact command as an exercise for the reader.